# Viewport Pixels trouble - Intel XDK

Tags: android, ios, intel, window-management

I'm creating a game in Intel XDK, and using their API to get the viewport width and height.  These are coming back at 1122 pixels and 746 pixels, respectively.

When adding my text at 150 pixels down and 100 pixels across its being placed in the center at the bottom.

```
var canvas= document.getElementById('game');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = 1122,height = 746;

ctx.fillText(window.innerWidth+' - '+window.innerHeight,100, 150);
```

That is writing on the screen 1122 - 748, but it's placed at the bottom of the screen. Not 100 pixels down by 150 pixels across. - It's directly in the middle.

Comment: You say you're using XDK's API to get the `width` and `height`, but you seem to be setting them to constants (line 3). What's up with that?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of what sets the size; imagine the whole canvas is the default size (300x150), and the CSS stretches that to display over the size of the screen.  The point where you write the text is in the middle bottom, as expected in that context, but doesn't look like the right spot.

There are a few ways to address this, but the easiest might be setting the size of the canvas (in JavaScript, to manage the draw order):

```
        var canvas= document.getElementById('game');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillText(window.innerWidth+' - '+window.innerHeight,100, 150);
```

If you add some alignment to the canvas style (top:0; left:0; position:absolute) and get rid of the scroll bars (body { overflow:hidden }) this should get you the output you expect.